# How do you get the field label of a PDF AcroField using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm making an app which allows you to fill out form fields.
I want to programatically gather the field names and their label.
I know how to get all the AcroFields, but I can't seem to find a way to get the related label.

Looking through the raw XFA form produced by iTextSharp, I can tell that each field is referenced by the description. But the order is messed up so I can't manually parse the XFA/XML of the PDF field.

Any ideas?

[Example form I'm working with](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/g-28.pdf)

Comment: If you've worked with HTML before then you know that you can create a `<label>` tag and associate it with a form field via the `for` attribute which is awesome. In PDFs, however, there is no such association. Instead, you've just got text that _happens_ to be near a text field. In your specific PDF, however, the `/TU` entry for each field is actually set and has what you'd probably call a "label". There's entries like `Check this box if the address is a suite.` and `Enter the Daytime Telephone Number of Attorney or Accredited Representative, if any.`

Comment: @ChrisHaas So I'm probably just stuck with manually mapping them? Was hoping to automate this...

Comment: If you're lucky (and you probably won't be, sorry) you could automate this. If you're dealing with government forms, you might get a little bit luckier. However, every field has a `/T` entry that you can _try_ to use to get a little closer and then maybe a human just has to inspect things.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks. Would you happen to know how to get the `/T` entry for a given AcroField?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'label' you mean the quickinfo / tooltip / alternate field name then the following code may help you. In the PDF there are XFA forms and old school acro forms inside. To retrieve the acroform names and labels you can use the following code. It is the java code but c# should be quite similar...

```
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = acroFields.getFields();
Iterator<Entry<String, Item>> it = fields.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, Item> entry = it.next();
    //name of the field
    String fieldName = entry.getKey();

    PdfDictionary d = entry.getValue().getMerged(0);
    PdfString quickInfo = d.getAsString(PdfName.TU);

    if(quickInfo==null){
        quickInfo= new PdfString("");
    }
    //Field description AKA quickinfo AKA alternate field name
    String alternateFieldName = quickInfo.toString();
}
```

Examples would be:
field name = feff004c0069006e00650031005f004500780070006c0061006e006100740069006f006e005b0030005d
alternate field name: Part 6. Additional Information. 1. Additional space for explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Collections;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Request.MapPath("~/editble.pdf"));

        // field names available in the subject PDF
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
        {
            sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1st set the path where your document is  located "~/editble.pdf", mention related name spaces, "iTextSharp" for PDF and collection for dictionary,then write the below code under event(pageload/button...) here taken one string builder to store the formfields.